# Why am I still getting an error to use an extsizes class?

Tags: document-classes, warnings, books, extsizes

I want to make a twocolumn A5 booklet with 8pt font and narrow margins. Here's what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,8pt,oneside,twocolumn,draft]{extbook} 
\usepackage[a5paper,textwidth=5in,textheight=7in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, extsizes, caption, cuted, titlesec}
```

However, I'm getting this error when running `pdflatex`:

```
Package ExtSizes Warning: It is better to use one of the extsizes classes, if you can.
```

How am I *not* using an extsizes class?! It says right there at the top: `\documentclass[...]{extbook}`, emphasis on the **extbook**. What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `extsizes` documentation says:

> There is also a package, extsizes.sty, which can be used with nonstandard document classes. But it cannot be guaranteed to work with any give class. **Don’t use it at the same time as one of the extsizes classes.**

The `extsizes` *package* is for when you cannot use one of the `extsizes` classes. So you should simply remove it.

---

Also, from the package code you see:

```
\PackageWarningNoLine{ExtSizes}{It is better to use one of the extsizes 
                          classes,^^J if you can}  %Comment out this
                            % line if you find it annoying!
```

Comment: @klasdfjasdf Also, note that that is not an error, it's just a warning :)